# [no file]:72: Missing \endcsname inserted. [}]

Tags: conditionals

friends!

I'm having a problem in latex with the following error. I do not know how to navigate this error and where the actual problem is. What is the meaning of [no file]:72 in error? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Errors:

```
[no file]:72: Missing \endcsname inserted. [}]
[no file]:72: LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}. [}]
[no file]:72: Extra \endcsname. [}]
[no file]:72: Package keyval Error: \par paper undefined. [}]
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! It's difficult to say something without an example of code reproducing the issue.

Comment: Thanks @egreg for the response. I solved the issue, it was related to geometry package.

Comment: A blank line sneaked in the list of options?

Comment: Yes, exactly @egreg. I have mentioned the issue in a comment below.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem after 4 hours of tedious job. I replaced every section of code one by one and finally I found the bug associated with the following code.

```
\geometry{
    paper=a4paper, % Change to letterpaper for US letter
    inner=2.5cm, % Inner margin
    outer=3.8cm, % Outer margin
    bindingoffset=2cm, % Binding offset
    top=1.5cm, % Top margin
    bottom=1.5cm, % Bottom margin
    showframe,% show how the type block is set on the page

}
```

The above code produces an error because there is a blank line just above the closing curly brace. The following code works well:

```
\geometry{
       paper=a4paper, % Change to letterpaper for US letter
       inner=2.5cm, % Inner margin
       outer=3.8cm, % Outer margin
       bindingoffset=2cm, % Binding offset
       top=1.5cm, % Top margin
       bottom=1.5cm, % Bottom margin
       showframe,% show how the type block is set on the page   
}
```

Comment: Not sure about how the geometry options are parsed, but since an empty line is converted into a `\par` token, I guess that it triggers processing for one further option; TeX expects to find the *characters* that should compose the name of this option, but finds the `\par` token, which is not allowed in such a name, and this casuses the error(s).  I can give you a more detailed explanation, but I need to know if are already aware of the `\csname ...\endcsname` construct.